# Run-time error '1004', Placing a formula in a acell

Tags: excel, vba, formula

===

EDIT: The answer seems to highlight that this has more to do with my syntax foo than anything else

===

All I'm trying to do I put a formula in a cell. It's a formula that I developed before using VBA and now I need to automate the process.

When I run the code it's fine until it gets to this line.

Then I receive this error-
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

The code is contained in a loop but that is for context or for any school boy errors I've made.

```
Sheets("Data Summary").Activate    

Dim startDate As Date
startDate = Now()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 7
startDate = DateAdd("d", 1, startDate)

cells.Range("B9").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(Discharged!$E$2:$E$200, " & _
                                " "">="" & startDate, " & _
                                " Discharged!$E$2:$E$200, " & _
                                " ""<"" & startDate.AddDays(1), " & _
                                " Discharged!$H$2:$H$200, " & _
                                " ""<24"" " 'here is the error

Next i
```

I've split up the formula into separate lines so that it's easier to read but it doesn't work if i put it all back on one line either.
If I edit the formula so that there is a space before the = then the code runs but the formula doesn't get activated with the sheet, it just sits there as a value.

I've had a look at the FormulaLocal function and the FormulaR1C1 as well but it doesn't seem to achieve a different result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Range("B9").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(Discharged!$E$2:$E$200," & """>=" & StartDate & """, Discharged!$E$2:$E$200, " & _
                            " ""<" & DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate) & """, Discharged!$H$2:$H$200, ""<24"")"
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that works now. Although it may take me another few minutes to figure out why.